# Windows phone Store app Font size Issue

Tags: fonts, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, font-size

I have created windows phone 8.1 Store app.

I have change setting: setting->ease of access->Text size to **MAX**

Now if I launch my app all fonts are disturbed to too larger font sizes, which was not happening in earlier silverlight apps

Is there any way to create app irrespective of device font size.As this is not messages or contacts there are many complex UI which can not be adjusted for every font sizes.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, XAML text elements support the property `IsTextScaleFactorEnabled` which is set to `true` by default. If you want your elements no to be affected by the ease of access settings simply set that property to false:

```
<TextBlock Text="Looking fresh" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False" />
```

You can read more here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868163.aspx

Comment: how can we do this in webview? there also html string is rendered on the basis of Text size settings.